# Send mouse click to minimized window. I don't want to maximize or move the mouse

Tags: c#

I want to simulate a mouseclick at a specific position inside a window that is hidden. So no maximizing the window or moving the mouse. I just want to send the right message.

Now I tried something like this

```
    DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    static int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    static int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

    private static IntPtr MakeLParam(int LoWord, int HiWord)
    {
        return (IntPtr)((HiWord << 16) | (LoWord & 0xffff));
    }

    public static void test()
    {
        int windowPtr = FindWindow(null, "Calculator");
        Console.WriteLine("pointer: " + windowPtr);
        int x = 260;
        int y = 180;
        IntPtr lParam = MakeLParam(x, y);
        IntPtr windowPointer = new IntPtr(windowPtr);

        PostMessage(windowPointer, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, lParam);
        PostMessage(windowPointer, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, lParam);
    }
```

I expected this program to click the 8 on the calculator ( if you set it to scientific ), but it doesn't do that.

How can I simulate that click? Please don't suggest finding the windows-control-element for the "8"-Button, this is not what I am trying to do here.

Comment: hi,  did u find a solution?